# Manga where the last two floors of a skyscraper get teleported through time

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

I am looking for a manga where the last two floors of a skyscraper get teleported through time.

The heroes travel through time with the building trying to going back to their period.

There is a group of kids that can see time as a black tide and don't age if they escape from it.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: The last two floors meaning the *top* two floors? Did they land (presumably with a "thud"), magically materialise on the floor of the new time period or stay up in the air?

Comment: Might be the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192787 . Ageless people unless they touch a body of "water" in both question. It's unanswered, but has more detail.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was migrated from manga/anime to sf/fantasy.

Comment: @dungarian - Because [Identification questions aren't on-topic on Anime:SE](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/what-wed-like-to-do-about-those-gosh-darn-identification-requests-questions) but because this contains some SF elements (notably time travel), it was migrated here rather than simply being closed and deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Your explanation resembles [Sprite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_(manga)) by [Ishikawa Yugo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%C5%ABgo_Ishikawa) as follows. These links to Wikipedia provide basic information on the respective subjects although unfortunately the plot of the manga isn't explained in detail.

> I am looking for a manga

Sprite is a manga

> last two floors of a skyscraper get teleported through time.

Not sure if top two, but residents (including a thug) on high floor of tall building are subject to phenomenon, and on the roof-top are group of children

> There is a group of kids that can see time as a black tide and don't age if they escape from it.

"Lost children" (although they've "lived" longer than any of us) are dealing with the black liquid that has affected time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you please describe how this matches the question?  Just posting a link isn't actually that helpful, especially since it might break someday.  Please include a summary of the link in your answer.

Comment: Sure, I just edited the answer. Hope this helps. Having said that, the question was to identify a manga, hence a straightforward answer of a potentially matching title and supplementary Wiki link should've sufficed, IMHO.

Comment: @dungarian - But what happens if the link dies? Now all they have to go on is the name of a popular soft drink.